# Automate workspace setup

Tags: ssh, automation, development, environment-variables, setup

I'm a software developer and I often have to switch between different projects, each with its own environment setup. Some actions I have to do each time include:

- creating ssh tunnels
- connecting database inspectors
- applying git stashes with local dev connection strings
- starting local servers
- opening specific IDE on the right project
- recovering Postman saved requests for the specific project
- set env variables
- ...

Those are all very basic tasks, but I have to do them every time with great time waste and chances to mess up.
It would be really cool to have something like:

- an "application" or "desktop icon" named after the project
- click on it and it will open a dedicated workspace with everything ready to start developing
- keep the local environment isolated

Is there something like this I can setup on my Mac?

Thanks

Comment: How about separate user accounts?

Comment: How many could I make? I mean I might reach overall some like 100 projects... but yeah something like dedicated VMs would sound good too.

Comment: tbh I have no idea how many accounts can be set up, sorry.

Comment: 100 accounts should be fine, but managing access rights might be a challenge (assuming some data sharing between the accounts/projects of course).

Comment: I’m not going to close this as off topic since it’s dangerously close to “I need an off site recommendation or software recommendation” and some people will gripe it’s “do my work for me, please” - but I see a clear question asking if this is possible and I love a good yes/no question from time to time to answer ***Yes - you could do that.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your question because I am interested in the same kind of thing for my own working environments. I don't have any complete answers but I have some experiences.

One approach that I am exploring for setting up the environment is using Keyboard Maestro, which can create scripts, simple or complex, much like AppleScript but with more features, especially including being able to find button images on the screen. It's not free ($36), but I was hooked enough by the 30-day free trial to spring for it. It allows you a wide variety of triggers to invoke scripts, from opening or closing an app to plugging in a USB device to keyboard hotkeys, text typing, or mouse gestures. There's also a very helpful user forum, which is a big plus.

One way that I'm using for SWITCHING defined workspaces is the free app CurrentKey Stats, which lets you define hotkeys to switch between desktop workspaces. It also has some hooks with AppleScript to identify when you have manually switched desktop spaces or to programmatically move to a new space.

I'm looking at being able to press a hotkey combination to go to a new screen and have KBM make sure that the screen is set up the way I want it to be for that project's work.

I recently went off on a sidetrack of also wanting to modify the desktop ICONS by changing the actual `Desktop` file, but the only way I've found to refresh that layout is by restarting Finder and that takes too much time to invoke just when moving from one workspace to another.

In looking for an alternative, I found http://www.shirt-ediss.me/clarity/ which I understood to do exactly that, give different desktop icon sets and arrangements on different desktops. After testing it, I realized that it changes the whole icon arrangement for all desktops. It can let you swap between different sets of different desktop icons, each with its own arrangement.

Clarity works by moving everything out of the Desktop folder rather than replacing the whole folder, so restarting Finder is not needed. That means it gets a new set of icons (none, or restoring the original set, or whatever) fairly quickly. However, if you've hiddent everything or are using a limited Desktop contents, you might have trouble finding things that have been put aside.

I hope these notes help you.

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm taking a look at those tools!

Comment: "One way that I'm using for SWITCHING defined workspaces is the free app CurrentKey Stats, which lets you define hotkeys to switch between desktop workspaces." -- Unfortunately, CurrentKey Stats has been withdrawn. I've been working on ways to replace its "Desktop Switching With Named Desktops and Hotkeys" features. My work in progress and successes have been reported in various threads on the Keyboard Maestro User Forum. Using hotkeys requires KBM, but naming and switching does not. I currently have 45 desktops, although only 32 are in use at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can automate things on macOS.

Before you start, since you are a developer - make a time budget for things you need to do so you can learn how to automate. Then have fun learning things, the first is how to split up a project into small tasks.

- https://xkcd.com/1205/ quick estimator for time budgets
- https://xkcd.com/1319/ much of what you seek could fall under continuous maintainance / ongoing development, though...

Have you tried seeing how much time you can waste on containers? (jk, not really) it’s far superior to making lots of user accounts and you can’t just use virtual environments for such a wide ranging project.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my 2¢...

Everything you listed can be scripted locally on your Mac, save one:  *keep the local environment isolated*

To do that, you need separate environments.  The best way to do this is with VMs, but instead of having a VM for each and every project, you can create a single base VM with a disk image in [Multiattach Mode](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#hdimagewrites).

What this allows you to do is create a base VM with your generic setup, then have as many VMs attach to it and they will create *differencing* drive images so that  each one will have it's customizations as you described but the disk size for each VM will only be the modifications you make.  The benefit here is that you can instantly clone a machine for a new project, make all your setups and when you're ready run that project you launch that VM.

You could do this on a MacBook Pro with a few VMs, but if you have "hundreds" you probably want to invest in some server grade (or workstation class) gear or even push it out to the cloud like Azure or AWS (I'm currently testing Oracle cloud and it's horrible IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some specific suggestions for a subset of your asks. Note that none of these are Mac-specific, but I've used them all successfully on a Mac for years (I'm using them right now!) My gain a lot for free by being UNIX-compatible ;)

## `.env` files

> - set env variables
> - applying git stashes with local dev connection strings

This is a technique for application configuration that avoids the need to dirty your source-controlled files just to make local configuration changes. A popular example is NPM's [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv).

The gist is that you have one or more `.env*` files in your project folder that are ignored by source control. When you start your applications in development mode, they read environment variables out of these files for their configuration. This allows you to set your development configuration *once* without worrying about source control.

Note that this also ties in well with [12-factor apps](https://12factor.net/config).

## SSH configuration

> - creating ssh tunnels

You can create a `~/.ssh/config` file to set defaults for use cases such as this. Here's an [example blog post](https://www.ateam-oracle.com/simplify-your-day-with-ssh-config-file-entries-and-self-closing-tunnels).

I use this *heavily* in my job, where I have to work with a hybrid of various old, crufty systems. It's a godsend.

## Docker/`docker-compose`

> - starting local servers

If your software fits it (which it probably will if you develop for Windows or Linux), [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) can be very useful for reproducing software on different environments. More generally, this technique is called "containerization." It's a very broad topic, but it's *very* popular these days for simplifying developer workflows. IMO, it's almost always worth the effort. If nothing else.

This can also be easily combined with `.env` files.